# sqlalchemy error when using whoosh_search and pagination

Tags: python, flask, pagination, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to paginate a text search result using sqlalchemy (I use flask-sqlalchemy) and whoosh. My simplified models.py looks like this

```
class User(db.Model):
    __searchable__ = ['username']

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % (self.username)

whooshalchemy.whoosh_index(app, User)
```

So I simply want to search my database for usernames. I thought I can do that with

```
search_result = models.User.query.whoosh_search(search_txt, MAX_SEARCH_RESULTS).paginate(1, MEMBERS_PER_PAGE, False)
```

where search_txt is my search text. This works if the result of the search is only one user. But if it is more than one user I get the following error

AttributeError: 'result' object has no attribute 'id'

I just started with sqlalchemy so it is probably some very simple mistake on my side?
thanks for your help
carl

edit: Ok figured out that the problem is connected to the variable MEMBERS_PER_PAGE. if MEMBERS_PER_PAGE is equal the number of search results, I get an error. Otherwise it works fine...

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug in Flask-WhooshAlchemy. There is a open pull request fixing the problem on the [github](https://github.com/gyllstromk/Flask-WhooshAlchemy/pull/14) page of Flask-WhooshAlchemy. I ended up using [Flask-WhooshAlchemy-Redux](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask-WhooshAlchemy-Redux), as suggested in the discussion on the pull request, and that fixed the pagination problem for me.